# Why is String#split("\n") and Array#join(' ') quicker than String#gsub(/\n/, ' ')?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have to remove all newlines from a large number of strings. In benchmarking `string.join("\n").split(' ')` vs `string.gsub(/\n/, ' ')`, I found that the split and join methods are much quicker, but have a hard time understanding why. I do not understand how splitting the string up into array elements each time it encounters a `\n`, then joining the array into a new string could possibly be quicker than just scan and replacing each `\n` with a `' '`.

```
sentence = %q[
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
  totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
  dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,
  sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam
  est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
  modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima
  veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea]
```

Check to verify the output is indeed the same for both methods:

```
puts sentence.split("\n").join(' ') == sentence.gsub(/\n/, ' ')
#=> true
```

Script used to benchmark:

```
def split_join_method(string)
  start = Time.now;
  1000000.times {  string.split("\n").join(' ') }
  puts "split_join: #{Time.now - start} s"
end

def gsub_method(string)
  start = Time.now;
  1000000.times {  string.gsub(/\n/, ' ') }
  puts "gsub: #{Time.now - start} s"
end

5.times do
  split_join_method(sentence)
  gsub_method(sentence)
end
```

Results:

```
#=> split_join: 6.753057 s
#=> gsub: 14.938358 s
#=> split_join: 6.16101 s
#=> gsub: 14.166971 s
#=> split_join: 5.946168 s
#=> gsub: 13.490355 s
#=> split_join: 5.781062 s
#=> gsub: 13.436135 s
#=> split_join: 5.903052 s
#=> gsub: 15.670774 s
```

Comment: I'm not sure why gsub is so much slower, but you'll find that `string.tr("\n", " ")` is much faster than either of your current methods.

Comment: You should also try a larger string, otherwise the regex compilation might well dominate the runtime of gsub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `gsub` takes more time for two reasons:

The first is that using a regex engine has an initial cost, at least to parse the pattern.

The second and probably the most important here is that the regex engine works with a dumb walk character by character and tests the pattern for each positions in the string when the split (with a literal string here) uses a fast string search algorithm (probably the Boyer-Moore algorithm).

Note that even if the split/join way is faster, it uses probably more memory since this way needs to generate new strings.

Note2: some regex engines are able to use this fast string search algorithm before the walk to find positions, but I have no informations about this for the ruby regex engine.

Note3: It may be interesting to have a better idea of what happens to include tests with few repeatitions but with larger strings. [edit] After several tests with @spickermann code, it seems that it doesn't change anything (or nothing very significative) even with very few repetitions. So the initial cost may be not so important.

Comment: Second argument is somewhat invalid. First because I don't think it's true for most modern regex engines and secondly because the pattern has length 1

Comment: @NiklasB.: the ruby regex engine is indeed a relatively advanced regex engine (there are a lot of features) but as I said I have no informations (and confirmations) about a pre-analysis. If you have links about that don't hesitate to share. However I don't think that the pattern length is important, the only important thing is that the pattern is a literal string (or contains/begins with a literal string) or not.

Comment: @NiklasB.: other question: how the regex engine consider `\n`? as a literal line-feed or as a special sequence of characters that represents a line-feed in a pattern?

Comment: `/\n/` is a simple newline character in the same way that `"\n"` is, the `\n` is converted to a newline before the regex engine sees anything.

Comment: @muistooshort: I don't think it is the case, for example if you type `"\p{L}"` in the console, it prints `"p{L}"` (not a surprise). This simple test may be a proof that the regex engine doesn't use the build-in string interpreter for a pattern.

Comment: But `\p{L}` is a regex pattern like `\s` whereas `\n` is a newline character just like `\t` is a tab.

Comment: @muistooshort: I have played with spickermann benchmark, and I have replaced `\n` with `,` (about the same number of occurences), conclusion: it doesn't change anything. So it seems that  `\n` do not receive any preferential treatment. (or at least it's not visible).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is comparing apples and oranges, because you compare a regexp method with a string search operation.

My benchmark cannot reproduce your observation that `split` combined with `join` are in general faster that a simple `gsub`, the `gsub` version is always faster. The only thing I can confirm is, that regexp matches are slower than string searches what is not very surprising.

Btw. `tr` is the fastest solution for this kind of problem:

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------
string_split:     5.390000   0.100000   5.490000 (  5.480459)
regexp_split:    14.220000   0.160000  14.380000 ( 14.413509)
string_gsub :     3.750000   0.090000   3.840000 (  3.832316)
regexp_gsub :    12.890000   0.130000  13.020000 ( 13.045899)
string_tr   :     2.480000   0.050000   2.530000 (  2.525891)
----------------------------------------- total: 39.260000sec

                      user     system      total        real
string_split:     5.450000   0.090000   5.540000 (  5.543735)
regexp_split:    14.340000   0.190000  14.530000 ( 14.552214)
string_gsub :     4.160000   0.120000   4.280000 (  4.543941)
regexp_gsub :    13.570000   0.200000  13.770000 ( 14.356955)
string_tr   :     2.390000   0.040000   2.430000 (  2.431676)
```

Code that I used for this benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

@string = %q[
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
  totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
  dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,
  sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam
  est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
  modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima
  veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea]

def string_split
  @string.split("\n").join(' ')
end

def regexp_split
  @string.split(/\n/).join(' ')
end

def string_gsub
  @string.gsub("\n", ' ')
end

def regexp_gsub
  @string.gsub(/\n/, ' ')
end

def string_tr
  @string.tr("\n", ' ')
end

n = 1_000_000
Benchmark.bmbm(15) do |x|
  x.report("string_split:")   { n.times do; string_split; end }
  x.report("regexp_split:")   { n.times do; regexp_split; end }
  x.report("string_gsub :")   { n.times do; string_gsub ; end }
  x.report("regexp_gsub :")   { n.times do; regexp_gsub ; end }
  x.report("string_tr   :")   { n.times do; string_tr   ; end }
end
```

Comment: Interesting, I have tested this code, but I obtain a totally different result. In short I obtain no difference between `regexp_split`, `string_gsub` and `regexp_gsub` (~11s). Other tests give similar results.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your `gsub` code, you are using regular expressions, which are slow for the reasons pointed out in Casimir's answer. Here is proof: if you change

```
string.gsub(/\n/, ' ')
```

to

```
string.gsub("\n", ' ')
```

then the gsub code is actually *faster* than the split/join code.